# Convert HTML to PDF using iTextSharp does not support Arabic language

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp to convert HTML Contents into PDF File ,but I have a problem when the HTML Content in Arabic it's be like this:
[image]

and that's my code:

```
Public Shared Function ExportToPDF(lang As String) As String
    Try
        Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter
        Dim htmlWrite As New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)

        divExport.RenderControl(htmlWrite)

        Dim text As String
        text = String.Format("<html><head><style type='text/css'>{0}</style></head><body>{1}</body></html>", "body{font-color:red;}", stringWrite.ToString)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(text)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()

        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.End()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

divExport :

```
     <div id="divExport">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <table>
         <tr>
        <td>Questions</td><td>الاسئلة</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <h2>Questions Answers</h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Device Type</td><td>جهاز الكمبيوتر</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

`XMLWorker` was not designed to be able to handle Arabic text, and to the best of my knowledge (ex-iText employee) it can not handle Arabic text.

The better solution would be to use `pdfHTML` (which is part of the iText 7 product family, and converts HTML5 and CSS3 to PDF).

In order to properly render Arabic (along with other non-western scripts) you also need `pdfCalligraph`, which was specifically designed to properly render non-western scripts.

[This link](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) offers more explanation on `pdfCalligraph`

Comment: what you think the best library to convert HTML to PDF without languages problems.

Comment: That's not a good question for StackOverflow. StackOverflow is about facts, not about opinions.